# Python + GPG (edit-key change password)

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm looking for a gpg Python library that let me change password for my key.
I saw python-gnupg but there aren't that function :(
Anyone can help me please? If is possibile i wish have also some examples from docs

Answer (score 0):

A cross-platform approach is difficult, but see here for a potential solution:
http://groups.google.com/group/python-gnupg/browse_thread/thread/93ea0b195097ccb1

Answer (score 0):

Python gnupg module already has a method (`GPG._handle_io`) to invoke gpg command and pass input to it and parse output. It may solve the portability issue.

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
result = gnupg.Verify(gpg)
gpg._handle_io(['--command-fd', '0', '--edit-key', keyname], StringIO(u'\n'.join(commands)), result)
```

`commands` is your command sequence to execute in edit-key mode. Note, some commands behave little differently when issuing them in `--no-tty` mode, eg. `save` command asks a `y` for confirmation.
`result` is an arbitrary gpg class and needed only to capture the output. See machine-readable output in `result.stderr`.